# SSH PuTTy error Unable to open address shell

Tags: putty

I run the command "gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh" on google cloud sdk shell in window 7 32bit.But I always get errors

[image]

What do I need to do or have something I can do to fix it please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a problem with putty.exe on Windows. The Windows version of putty does not like the command line options that `gcloud` is generating.

To get around this type this command:

```
gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh --dry-run
```

This will print the command line to run putty.exe. It looks like this:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\putty.exe' -t -P 6000 -i 'C:\Users\username\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk' username@devshell-vm-12345678-1234-4992-8505-01234567890ab.cloudshell.dev 'DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID=development-12345 bash -l'
```

Copy that command line and replace single quotes with double quotes and delete the part that ends with `'DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID=development-12345 bash -l'` as this is the part causing a problem on Windows.

Example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\putty.exe" -t -P 6000 -i "C:\Users\username\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk" username@devshell-vm-12345678-1234-4992-8505-01234567890ab.cloudshell.dev
```

**Second Method:**

You can also start putty.exe manually and then fill in the options in the GUI.

The SSH port is `6000`

The example above shows you the putty ssh private key:

```
C:\Users\username\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk
```

The example above shows you the hostname:

```
devshell-vm-12345678-1234-4992-8505-01234567890ab.cloudshell.dev
```

Comment: Absolutely correct thank you very much.I would like to ask if the putty version supports you?

Comment: @VũĐạt - I don't understand your question. Putty is a windows program, it works fine for me. I prefer to use Bitvise on Windows.