# How to push the SSH keys from windows localhost to GCP cloud shell?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to access GCP cloud shell from my windows localhost by referring to the blog - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-the-ability-to-connect-to-cloud-shell-from-any-terminal

Steps I followed -

```
1) install gcloud Alpha Commands

2) gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh
```

The second step gave the following WARNINGS and then created SSH key pair and pushed it to the cloud shell but I am still not able to connect to cloud shell -

> WARNING: The PuTTY PPK SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
>   WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist. WARNING:
>   The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist. WARNING: You do
>   not have an SSH key for gcloud. WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed
>   to generate a key. This tool needs to create the directory
>   [C:\Users\myuser.ssh] before  being able to generate SSH keys.
>
> ```
> Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y
>
> API [cloudshell.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [XXXXXXXXX].  Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)? (y/N)?  Y
>
> Enabling service [cloudshell.googleapis.com] on project [XXXXXXXXX]... Operation "operations/acf.0987cdf-34gh-7ghj-09op-083532nclafo" finished successfully. 
> Pushing your public key to Cloud Shell...
> ```

When I try this command - `gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh` again. I get below error -

[image]

And I don't see my public key added to the Compute Engine -> Metadata section of my GCP console. Can anyone please help me in resolving this?

Comment: Unrelated comment: Why do you need to connect your environment to Cloud Shell? What's the advantage? What is your use case? (I discover this feature with your question, and I'm surprised!!)

Comment: Could this help: [SSH PuTTy error : Unable to open connection, Network error cannot assign requested address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908389/11602913)?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Windows-specific issue. PuTTY can't handle a command line `gcloud` passes to it.

There is a workaround you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908389/11602913